# Second Order Differential Equation Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Got this question on my FP3 homework - if anyone could help me out I'd really appreciate it.

.

[image: If anyone could help me with this question I'd really appreciate it]

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What part(s) are you having trouble with?

Comment: @rewildman what is y?

Comment: @CameronBuie I'm just not sure how to start it - like the other user asked, we're not told what y is so I'm unsure of where the dy/dt and dy/dx have come from

Comment: This is an Euler differential equation. Have you covered these in class? You can rewrite it in the form $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$.Is this a three part question, where you need to prove (i) and (ii) and then solve the ODE?

Answer (score 0):

Well, note that we must assume that $y$ is some differentiable function of $x$--equivalently, of $t$--as otherwise it makes no sense to talk about $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $\frac{dy}{dt}.$

So, let's assume that $y$ is a differentiable function of $x.$ Differentiate $y$ with respect to $t$ and apply the Chain Rule to get your first identity. Then, differentiate your first identity with respect to $t,$ applying Product and Chain Rules and your first identity, to get the second identity.

For the last part, use the two identities that you found to rewrite the equation $$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-3x\frac{dy}{dx}+13y=0$$ in terms of $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2},\frac{dy}{dt},$ and $y,$ which will give you a nice differential equation that you should be able to solve to get $y$ as a function of $t.$ Once you've done that, simply make the substitution $t=\ln x$ to get $y$ as a function of $x.$